# Test::MockModule claims "method does not exist"

Tags: perl, mocking

I try to mock a function in [Net::Twitter](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-Twitter/lib/Net/Twitter.pod):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::MockModule;

my $mock = Test::MockModule->new('Net::Twitter');
$mock->redefine('update', sub {
    # ...
});
```

but when I run this, I get:

> Net::Twitter::update does not exist! at wtf.pl line 8.

Why is that and how can I actually mock the `Net::Twitter::update` function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message means that it can't find `Net::Twitter::update` to overwrite. That's pretty clear. The question is, *why?*.

If you take a look at a [Net::Twitter](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Twitter) object with [Data::Printer](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Printer), you'll see that there is indeed no `update` method apparent. In fact, it's not even an object of the type `Net::Twitter`.

```
use Net::Twitter;
use Data::Printer;

my $t = Net::Twitter->new;
p $t;
```

On my machine with the currently newest Net::Twitter installed, it's a `Net::Twitter_v4_01042_with__Legacy`, which is likely a dynamically created package.

```
Net::Twitter_v4_01042_with__Legacy  {
    Parents       Net::Twitter::Core
    public methods (22) : apihost, apirealm, apiurl, arrayref_on_error, BUILD, DESTROY, has_error, http_code, http_message, is_list_member, is_list_subscriber, is_subscribed_list, meta, new, searchapiurl, trends, tvhost, tvrealm, tvurl, twittervision, update_twittervision, upload_url
    private methods (5) : _clear_error, _error_return_val, _http_response, _parse_result, _twitter_error
    internals: {
        apirealm               "Twitter API",
        apiurl                 "https://api.twitter.com/1",
        arrayref_on_error      0,
        clientname             "Perl Net::Twitter",
        clienturl              "http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-Twitter/",
        clientver              4.01042,
        decode_html_entities   0,
        _error_return_val      undef,
        _json_handler          Cpanel::JSON::XS,
        <<MOP>>                Class::MOP::Class::Immutable::Moose::Meta::Class,
        netrc_machine          "api.twitter.com",
        searchapiurl           "https://search.twitter.com",
        source                 "twitterpm",
        ssl                    1,
        tvhost                 "twittervision.com:80",
        tvrealm                "Web Password",
        tvurl                  "http://twittervision.com",
        twittervision          0,
        upload_url             "https://upload.twitter.com/1",
        useragent              "Net::Twitter/4.01042 (Perl)",
        useragent_args         {},
        useragent_class        "LWP::UserAgent"
    }
}
```

If you try [looking for a `sub update` in the entire Net::Twitter distribution](https://grep.metacpan.org/search?q=sub%20update&qd=Net-Twitter&qft=), you'll find nothing. It's not part of a role, it just doesn't exist.

But that does not mean it's not there. I dug a little deeper, and found [an `update` in Net::Twitter::Role::API::REST](https://metacpan.org/source/MMIMS/Net-Twitter-4.01042/lib/Net/Twitter/Role/API/REST.pm#L195). It's defined using the [`twitter_api_method` function from Net::Twitter::API](https://metacpan.org/source/Net::Twitter::API#L26). It does a bunch of things and then uses Moose's meta layer to install the method into some class – probably `Net::Twitter_v4_01042_with__Legacy` on my machine` – and even brings its own meta method class [Net::Twitter::Meta::Method](https://metacpan.org/source/MMIMS/Net-Twitter-4.01042/lib/Net/Twitter/API.pm#L119).

So it's fairly obvious why [Test::MockModule](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::MockModule) wouldn't find `Net::Twitter::update`. It simply never

But how do we mock it for testing?

I believe the simplest approach, though certainly not a very nice one, is to overwrite `update` in the package that it exists in. For that, you need to create an object and check.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::MockModule;
use Net::Twitter;

my $mock = Test::MockModule->new( ref( Net::Twitter->new ) );
$mock->redefine(
    'update',
    sub {
         ... # will die with 'unimplemented'
    }
);

my $nt = Net::Twitter->new->update;
```

This code is a little wasteful, because it needs to create an object just to check  what package it ended up in, but it works.

> Unimplemented at /home/simbabque/code/scratch/scratch.pl line 236.

Comment: Thanks, that did it! Well, almost. It even makes a difference how you call the `Net::Twitter` constructor: without arguments, it's a `Net::Twitter_v4_01042_with__Legacy`, like you wrote, but if you pass `traits => [qw/API::RESTv1_1/]`, it's a `Net::Twitter_v4_01042_with__API_RESTv1_1`. So the constructor call in the code under test must match the mock object creation. Weird, even for Perl...

Comment: @Robert it's weird indeed. But th architecture is interesting. I suggest going through their github and reading the commit history to learn more about the architecture and why they made these decisions. I believe there are good reasons. Often this kind of complexity is overengineering, but from what I've seen in there this might be pretty smart.